Eliminar registros con mas de X tiempo en la tabla
Algo de contexto:
Buenas, tengo una duda, estoy buscando, pero no estoy muy seguro de cómo hacerlo, sé que DATEADD me sirve para tomar la fecha/hora en un formato específico, pero no estoy muy seguro de cómo usarlo, apenas empecé en sql.
Duda:
Quisiera saber cómo podría hacer para que cada dato con más de 5 minutos de antigüedad se borre de la tabla? Tengo una variable que guarda tanto la fecha como la hora, así que quería saber cómo podría hacerlo
ejemplo de tabla
CREATE TABLE [Datos_temporales](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fechaCaptura] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


que parte de la documentacion https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 te confundio???

necesitas sumarle 5 minutos a la fecha de la tabla, y luego compararla con la fecha actual y fijarte que sea menor.. si es asi, ya pasaron 5 minutos ;)

@gbianchi entiendo el usar DELETE, pero la idea es que borre cada 5 minutos, para asi se eliminen los mas antiguos y solo se mantengan los mas nuevos y continue el ciclo

Bueno.. eso no seria ideal en una DB.. pero bueno, supongamos que vale... cual seria el problema?? lo que necesitas es un cron en la db que haga que se ejecute el SP que contiene eso...

@gbianchi siendo especifico, es un proyecto de prueba, donde digamos guarda datos de venta, digo asi pero realmene solo tiene la lista de productos, y no hace nada mas, solo guarda datos que no se vuelven a tocar, por ejemplo, se registra una 'venta', solo tiene los productos realmente, y se acumulan sin mas, como son datos que no uso, me gustaria eliminarlos, para que no ocupen espacio de forma innecesaria

@gbianchi encontre este codigo, lo modifique un poco, me podrias decir si esta bien ?
CREATE PROCEDURE temporales
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE Now    DATETIME
SELECT  Now    = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDTIME(), 112))
DELETE FROM LogData WHERE fechaCaptura < DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @Now)
END
nota, cada NOW lleva un arroba, me toco borralor

no se si esta bien.. lo probaste?? de paso.. entendiste lo que hace el where??? contamelo en español y te vas a dar cuenta si esta bien o mal...

Igual, salvo que no se.. guardes miles de miles de registros por minuto.. nunca nada en una DB va a ocupar tanto espacio como para que tengas que preocuparte por este micromanagement que estas tratando de hacer...

@gbianchi si entiendo que hace, es la condicion que dice en este caso, eliminar donde fechacapturada sea menor que la hora actual o al menos eso es lo que pretendo hacer, si esta mal agradezco la correccion, y para aclarar por que hago esto, es una idea para el lugar donde quiero hacer la pasantia, cada cierto tiempo se hacen consultas en unas tablas que solo se dar permiso de acceso de digamos, 1 minuto, y como se bloquea la tabla, la consulta se bloquea, aclaro que eso es lo que me dijeron, no se que tan alta es la consulta

El delete va a bloquear las consultas mas que las consultas en si, que deberian no tener problemas si fueran solo select. Un delete es mucho mas bloqueante. Pero bueno.. lo que te preguntaba, era que me explicaras (y es algo que en realidad deberian explicarte donde estas haciendo la pasantia) que significaba exactamente esa condicion. Fijate que dice que la fechadecaptura debe ser menor a la fechaactual mas 1 minuto... o sea.. que si capture recien, me lo va a borrar.. es eso lo que queres?

delete from [Datos_temporales] where DATEADD(minute,5,[fechaCaptura]) <  GETDATE()


Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).
